# Peterson's algorithm using disk instead of memory

Tags: algorithm, locking

I would like to implement disk based Peterson's algorithm for mutual exclusion between processes running on two separate servers having access to the same storage.

There are several problems I would like to find an opinion of

**1) Can I safely write single byte to a disk without impacting other bytes?**

I am concerned that when writing to a disk, a sector, or a block (of 4k for example) could be really written down, this way overwriting other process settings (see next point that may actually benefit out of it, if this is the case.)

**Should I write these bytes next to each other or should I write each of them in the beginning of a block that I know the storage would write in one shot?**

**2) How can I detect crash of a server in a critical section?**

Does it make sense to use an 'expected timeout' in stead of 'true' in the place of a flag? Of course this way I would be using 'long' instead of 'byte' to store a flag. I am assuming both servers are having synchronized time.
The P0 process would store instead of 'true' a timestamp when the P1 process could took it over in case P0 fails to complete. I am not 100% sure that I could safely write a 'long' value without having it only partially read by the other server...

I hope that all these concerns are clear, and I am not making some fundamental mistake trying to use this algorithm.

Any thoughts? Thank you for interest or time to read it.